# PHP Select everything from database if $_GET empty

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to select everything from my database if the user doesn't select anything in the dropdown menu or select the one he choose there. So basically what I want to do is check if the $filter is empty, if yes then select everything, but don't know how to do that. Here's my select which works good if I choose something from the dropdown list, but ofc it gives an undefined index warning until I select something.

```
<?php
$visibility = 1;
$filter = $_GET['slct'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, description, address, phone, phone2, email, company, job, visibility, filter, confirmed, userid FROM cards WHERE visibility = ? AND filter = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("is", $visibility, $filter);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
```

and the select:

```
<select name="slct" id="slct" onchange="form.submit()">
<option value="One">One</option>
<option value="Two">Two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get the global `slct`

```
$visibility = 1; 
$filter = isset($_GET['slct']) ? $_GET['slct'] : "";
```

After Try to construct the Query whether `slct` is set or not

```
$baseQuery = "SELECT id, name, description, address, phone, phone2, email, company, job, visibility, filter, confirmed, userid FROM cards WHERE visibility = ?" ;
$filterPart = isset($_GET['slct']) ? " AND filter = ?" : "";
```

Prepare the statement and bind param accordingly and execute

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $baseQuery. $filterPart);
if(isset($_GET['slct'])){
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $visibility, $filter);
}else{
   $stmt->bind_param("is", $visibility);
} 
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: It solves the warning problem, but doesn't select anything because there is no default value. Each card (that's what I want to show with the data from database) has different filter.

Comment: You want to get Everything in the Database if no filter is selected?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to select everything from there. For example, I want this: ```$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, description, address, phone, phone2, email, company, job, visibility, filter, confirmed, userid FROM cards WHERE visibility = ?");```

Comment: I hope the new answer will help

Comment: It works perfectly! The only problem I found was with this part: ```$stmt->bind_param("is", $visibility);``` Had to remove the 's'. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Happy to hear that